# Virtual hosts redirecting incorrectly

Tags: apache2, dns, virtual-hosts

Hi guys I'm having problems with the following virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.domain1.com
ServerAlias domain1.com *.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vvr
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/vvr>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
ServerName www.domain2.com
ServerAlias domain2.com *.domain2.com

# Send servlet for context / jsp-examples to worker named worker1
JkMount / worker1
JkMount /domainDocuments worker1 

# Send JSPs for context /jsp-examples/* to worker named worker1
JkMount /* worker1
JkMount /domainDocuments/* worker1
```

This configuration is working when I enter www.domain1.com, however when I try to access only the domain name:

http://domain1.com , The site is redirecting me to www.domain2.com? Why is this hapenning. Thanks alot.

Comment: What IPs are www.domain1.com and domain1.com resolving to?

Comment: The same one 66.229.xx.xxx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VirtualHost definitions look good to me.  You might check your .htaccess file to make sure there are no redirects sending domain1.com to www.domain2.com.